# What is a 'bagplot', or 'bivariate boxplot'?

Tags: data-visualization, bivariate, boxplot

I've [found a paper](http://www.r-project.org/user-2006/Slides/Mizera.pdf) which introduces the multidimensional (bivariate here) version of the boxplot - a bagplot. What is that bagplot exactly? I can see the series of nested polygons based on vertices, one of those polygons being declared as a bagplot. What is the idea of nested polygon building? Which of the polygons is the bagplot (central or holding the average number of points)? Do the edges of a bagplot possess some useful properties (like specifically dividing the point set)?

Comment: There is an article by Rousseeuw, Pits and Tukey in American Statistician that explains these. I am, for some reason, having trouble pasting the link, but Googling "bagplot" and "Tukey" will find it

Comment: Only found it for outrageous price. Still searching.

Comment: If you have access to any decent library, they should have it. American Statistician is pretty widely subscribed to. There was also something on quora, but I didn't look at it.

Comment: Rousseeuw and Ruts have another article online besides the American Statistician one [in postscript format](ftp://ftp.win.ua.ac.be/pub/preprints/97/artbag.ps) for free.

Comment: @AndyW, Asking you as a SPSS fellow: how do you think is it possible to do it via GPL somehow? Are you going to invent the code for us SPSSers?

Comment: @ttnphns - in SPSS if you have identified the points that create the convex hull you can plot them. See [here](https://andrewpwheeler.wordpress.com/2014/03/04/visualizing-multi-level-data-using-ellipses/) for one example. Identifying those points though is the hardest part. If I had to do this in SPSS I would just call the R code and return them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's an example with notes:

Here is the article `The Bagplot: A Bivariate Boxplot` by Peter J. Rousseeuw , Ida Ruts & John W. Tukey from `The American Statistician`: http://venus.unive.it/romanaz/ada2/bagplot.pdf

From the abstract of that article:

> The “depth median” is the deepest location, and it is  surrounded by a
>   “bag” containing the n/2 observations with largest depth. Magnifying
>   the bag by a factor 3 yields the “fence” (which is not plotted).
>   Observations between the bag and the fence are marked by a light gray
>   loop, whereas observations outside the fence are flagged as outliers.
>   The bagplot visualizes the location, spread, correlation, skewness,
>   and tails of the data.

Here's an illustration of the key parts:

[image]

Additional discussion can be found in the following:

- https://fenix.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/downloadFile/395137801290/paper.pdf
- http://www.thl.fi/publications/morgam/theses/kontto_2007.pdf
- http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1470160X14004695
- http://search.r-project.org/library/aplpack/doc/bagplot.pdf
- ftp://ftp.univates.br/ensino/Softwares/R%20matem%C3%A1tica/R/R-2.14.2/library/aplpack/pdf/bagplot.pdf
- http://eprints.maynoothuniversity.ie/6085/1/State%20of%20the%20Art%20in%20Patterns%20for%20Point%20Cluster%20Analysis_EtienneDevogeleMcArdleICCSA2014.pdf
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagplot
- https://books.google.com.au/books?id=66gQCi5JOKYC&pg=PA59&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false
- https://wis.kuleuven.be/stat/robust/papers/1999/struyfrousseeuw-depthcharacterizesdistribution-jmv.pdf

From the [help](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/aplpack/html/bagplot.html) docs of the `aplpack` package (for `R` users):

> A bagplot is a bivariate generalization of the well known boxplot. It
>   has been proposed by Rousseeuw, Ruts, and Tukey. In the bivariate case
>   the box of the boxplot changes to a convex hull, the bag of bagplot.
>   In the bag are 50 percent of all points. The fence separates points in
>   the fence from points outside. It is computed by increasing the the
>   bag. The loop is defined as the convex polygon containing all points
>   inside the fence. If all points are on a straight line you get a
>   classical boxplot. bagplot() plots bagplots that are very similar to
>   the one described in Rousseeuw et al. Remarks: The two dimensional
>   median is approximated. There are known difficulties with small data
>   sets (But I think it is not wise to make a (graphical) summary of e.g.
>   10 points.)
>
> In case people want to plot multiple (overlappIng) bagplots, it is
>   convenient if the plots are semi-transparent. For this reason the
>   transparency flag has been added to the bagplot command. If
>   transparency==TRUE the alpha layer is set to '99' (hex). This causes
>   the bagplots to appear semi-transparent, but ONLY if the output device
>   is PDF and opened using: pdf(file="filename.pdf", version="1.4"). For
>   this reason, the default is transparency==FALSE. This feature as well
>   as the arguments to specify different colors has been proposed by
>   Wouter Meuleman.

And an example:

```
library(aplpack)
attach(mtcars)
bagplot(wt, mpg, xlab="Car Weight", 
        ylab="Miles Per Gallon",
        main="Bagplot Example", 
        transparency = TRUE, 
        show.whiskers = FALSE, 
        # note that data a 'fence' separates inliers from outliers, 
        # and a 'loop' indicates the points outside the bag but 
        # inside the fence. In the 'bag' are 50 percent of all 
        # points
        show.loophull = TRUE, # draw 'loop'?
        show.baghull = TRUE)  # draw 'bag'?
```

[image]

related questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501282/plot-multiple-series-of-data-into-a-single-bagplot-with-r
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31893559/r-adding-alpha-bags-to-a-2d-or-3d-scatterplot
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30301108/plot-a-circle-convex-hull-arround-a-given-percentage-of-points/

Comment: Update: someone made a ggplot2 geom for this: https://gist.github.com/benmarwick/00772ccea2dd0b0f1745 . maybe an enterprising user could turn this into a package?